# Append a text to a file in linux

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I am trying to append a text to the existing file in Linux. Currently, instead of appending it to the existing line, it appends content to the next line. How can I append to the same line /or a specific line?

```
echo 'He' > /tmp/newfile
echo 'llo World' >> /tmp/newfile
```

the output of the file comes in two-line like the one below

```
He
llo World
```

how can I bring output  like the below one

```
Hello World
```

How to bring the appending text to the same /specific line?

Comment: Incorrect dupe because it is NOT about echoing out without newline. It was `How to bring the appending text to the same /specific line?`. There might be some other dupe but this one is not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `sed` to append text in same line:

```sh
echo 'He' > /tmp/newfile
sed -i.bak '1s/$/llo World/' /tmp/newfile
cat /tmp/newfile

Hello World
```

`1s/$/.../` will only append given text at the end of line #1

Answer (score 1):

See `man echo`. You need `-n` to not append a trailing newline. If your shell's builtin `echo` does not support `-n` you need to use `/bin/echo`.